# Error occurred when I used tensor flow lite custom model

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow

I faced an issue while running an object detection program using tensor flow lite costum model.I am attaching the error code bellow.

```
classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0] # Class index of detected objects IndexError: list index out of range
```